# Решение вывода запланированной записи на Вордпресс сайте

Tags: wordpress

Нет ли готового решения для закрепления определенной записи в определенный день, месяц, год на верх? Или вывода записи в определенный день, месяц, год в нужном месте? На Вордпресс.

Comment: Закрепление - штатная фича, а для планирования вывода есть масса плагинов . Учить пользоваться оф. каталогом

Comment: Штатные фичи не подходят

Comment: В вопросе ты спрашивал именно про это.